# Gravity Forms, multiple conditions in shortcode

Tags: conditional-tags, plugin-gravity-forms

Gravity forms offers a shortcode for conditional display based on responses.

> [gravityforms action="conditional" merge_tag="{:3}"
>   condition="less_than" value="30"] Your value is less than 30
>   [/gravityforms]

Is there a way to use TWO conditions in this shortcode? For example, I need to do greater than 10 and less than 30, like:

> [gravityforms action="conditional" merge_tag="{:3}"
>   condition="greater_than, less_than" value="10,30" ] Your value is
>   greater than 10 and less than 30 [/gravityforms]

The above doesn't work, but wondering if anyone has found a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest the singular and plural versions of the shortcode:

`[gravityforms action="conditional" merge_tag="{:3}" condition="greater_than" value="10"]
[gravityform action="conditional" merge_tag="{:3}" condition="less_than" value="30"]Your value is greater than 10 less than 30[/gravityforms]
[/gravityforms]`

More details on that here:

https://gravitywiz.com/gravity-forms-conditional-shortcode/

- OR -

You can use this snippet to create multiple conditions in a single shortcode:

https://gist.github.com/spivurno/9db18385ed1d1f11a897bdfa8a1f2007

`[gravityforms action="conditional" relation="and"
value="{:3}" operator="greater_than" compare="10"
value2="{:3}" operator2="less_than" compare2="30"]
Your value is greater than 10 less than 30
[/gravityforms]`

Comment: Thank you! The nested solution worked! I didn't realize I could nest them if I changed the plural. (However, need to remove the "s" on the end of the closing tag on the nested shortcode as pasted above). Note: The second snippet seems to no longer work with the latest version of GF.